# How to reliably get Elasticsearch index size in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm currently using a Python script to receive tweets from a twitter stream and send them to an Elasticsearch index. My next step is to try and build some form of a safeguard that stops the streaming process once the index has reached a desired file size (say 2GB). I've obtained the store size in bytes but this size dramatically reduces after streaming has finished (with my limited knowledge I assume Elasticsearch is optimizing the index) leaving me with actually less than the desired file size.

Is there any reliable way to find what the exact file size will be and use it as a way to stop the stream?

My original idea was to stop streaming after a certain amount of tweets but this is unreliable as each tweet is of a different size not giving a reliable way to make sure it does not exceed a file size.

Comment: Can you run your indexer as a daemon and just sleep when you hit 2GB? You could then poll the index size every x seconds and see if you can restart indexing if the size is under your threshold.

Comment: That's a good idea! Yes I can run the elasticsearch instance and the script in the background

Comment: Tried it and while it was a good idea it didnt work. While my Python script is connected to the Elasticsearch instance it wont optimise the size. I think I'll just have to set it and forget it, can't do much about it.